# Swap numbers in a string

Tags: java

I've the below program.

```
public class swapping {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String num = "31254";

        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE, maxIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < num.length(); i++) {
            if (num.charAt(i) > max) {
                max = num.charAt(i);
                maxIndex = i;
            }
        }
        swap(num, num.charAt(0), maxIndex);
    }

    private static void swap(String num, char charAt, int maxIndex) {
         System.out.println("number is " + num + " Initial char is " + charAt
                    + " Maximum is " + maxIndex);
            char t = charAt;
            char s = num.charAt(maxIndex);
            System.out.println("numbers:" + t + " " + s);
            char temp = t;
            t = s;
            s = temp;
            System.out.println("Final string after swap is " + num);
    }

}
```

here my aim is to get the maximum number in the string to be swapped with the first number in the string. i.e. I want to convert `31254` to `51234`. But i'm unable to know how to do this.

```
number is 31254 Initial char is 3 Maximum is 3
numbers:3 5
Final string after swap is 31254
```

Here the swapping is not getting done, the previous number is getting printed. please let me know how to print the desired output.

Thanks

Comment: `charAt()` use 0-based indexes so `charAt(5)` is a *oops* for your string.

Comment: Also note that this `charAt` is doomed to failure, string "19", max = 9..

Comment: Hi @RC, based on your comment, i've updated my code, but here I'm still unable to swap, it prints the same old number.

Comment: [Here](http://paste.ofcode.org/bruiqTSqvBxwY3YX7fwwUS) is an alternative way where I convert it and work with arrays

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try the below program.

```
String num = "31254";

    int maxIndex = 0;
    char maxString = num.charAt(0);
    for (int i = 1; i < num.length(); i++) {
        if (num.charAt(i) > maxString) {
            maxString = num.charAt(i);
            maxIndex = i;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(maxString);
    System.out.println(maxIndex);

    String str1 = num.substring(1,maxIndex);
    String str2 = num.substring(maxIndex+1,num.length());
    String str3 = num.charAt(maxIndex)+str1+num.charAt(0)+str2;
    System.out.println(str3);
```

Answer (score 4):

Pay attention what you are passing to the method.

You are passing the actual character in the first and max position: `3` and `5` in this case.

But then, after you print them, you call:

```
    char t = num.charAt(initial);
    char s = num.charAt(max);
```

`charAt` expects the *index* of the character in the string. The index should be an integer, but you are passing it a **char** value (the character `3` and the character `5`).

Now, in Java, characters are considered numbers between 0 and 65535 - the unicode value of the character. So it allows you to pass a character where you should have passed an integer. The unicode value of `3` is 51, and for `5` it's 53. So you are actually telling it "give me the character in the string `num` which is in position 51".

This is not what you intended.

Instead of doing that, you should make the method accept *the index* of the first character and *the index* of the max character. Then, using `charAt` will be correct. But pay attention to also use `charAt` for your print at the beginning.

```
private static void swap(String num, int initialIndex, int maxIndex) {
    ...
}
```

---

Your other problem is that you are not actually swapping the characters inside the string.

What you did was swap the variables that contain the two characters, `t` and `s`. So now `t` contains what `s` contained, and `s` contains what `t` contained.

However, this has no bearing on the original string `num`. You have not done anything with the string itself.

One thing to remember is that in Java, you cannot change a string. It's *immutable*. If you have a string object, Java doesn't give you any way to change things inside it. It only lets you read parts of it, not write.

What you *can* do is assign a new string value to `num`. In this new string, you will put the value of the max character in the 0 position, and put the value of what was in the first position, in the max character position. And you'll copy all the other characters in the same positions where they were.

So you'll need to create a temporary string, loop on the original string character by character, and in each position, ask yourself "what character should I add to my new string at this round?". And then add that character to the string with a `+` operator.

Finally, assign the new, temporary string to `num`.

(Note: there are more efficient ways to do this in Java, like using a `StringBuffer` or `StringBuilder`, but I get the impression that you are not there yet in your studies of Java).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply, i've changed my code based on the above, but the problem is i'm unable to swap it, still it prints te old number.:(

Comment: Thats because you're not modifying num.  You need something like: temp=num.charAt(0); num.charAt(0) = num.charAt(maxInt); num.charAt(maxInt) = temp;

Comment: OK, I added a second part to my reply.

Answer (score 1):

`Initial` is a char. `charAt` use an integer, so the char will converted in the acii code of `3` wich is `51`. So your line is equals to `num.charAt(51) and that is out of range.

So hyou have to change the signature of your mathod to `private static void swap(String num, int initial, int max)`

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it in just 3 lines. Note that for digits, chars are 1 byte each.

```
byte[] array = number.getBytes();
Arrays.sort(array);
number = number.replaceFirst("(.)(.*?)(" + (array[array.length - 1] - '0') + ")", "$3$2$1");
```

Not only is this code quite terse - using regex to perform the swap in one statement - it also automatically handles the edge case of the largest digit being at the start (in which case no match/replacement will be made).

---

Here's some test code:

```
String number = "31254";
byte[] array = number.getBytes();
Arrays.sort(array);
number = number.replaceFirst("(.)(.*?)(" + (array[array.length - 1] - '0') + ")", "$3$2$1");
System.out.println(number);
```

Output:

```
51234
```